# Quantum entanglement question

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does quantum entanglement occur by physical itersection? When I google the question it mentions quantum interaction. Is that by intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Entanglement happens as a consequence of normal physical interactions. Not only that, but any physical interaction will almost always leave particles in an entangled state. It is the most common outcome of interaction.